# Css round button border loading animation on click

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I am trying to achieve this

https://codepen.io/jerrylow/pen/eXmroN?editors=1100

This is my button

```
<button type="button" rel="tooltip"
                            class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-round">
                            <span></span>
                            <i class="material-icons">save</i>
                        </button>
     height: 30px;
        min-width: 30px;
        width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 24px;
    height: 41px;
    min-width: 41px;
    width: 41px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 41px;
    color: #ff9800;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #ff9800;
    border: 1px solid currentColor
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 hsla(0,0%,60%,.14),0 3px 1px -2px hsla(0,0%,60%,.2),0 1px 5px 0 hsla(0,0%,60%,.12);
    margin: .3125rem 1px;
    outline: 0;
    transition: box-shadow .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,1,1),background-color .2s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
    will-change: box-shadow,transform;
```

The button should be round, I tried changing the button to round, yet the animation is sqaured, changing values in keyframe too did not help much

I want to use it on click of button.
I am not very good in css animations, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't make up a codepen off your code. I think the styles aren't for one songle element. Please, create a running pen https://codepen.io/, so we can better see what you've tried and work on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I reasoned a bit on it and my guess is that the animated border is a 2px tall span that runs along the border-box of the button, that is always squared regardless of the border-radius. My guess is that is not possible.